# BDD request with inner join with Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I'm new with Yii Framework.
My aim is to display all the "tablettes" owned by the current user.

In my model i have 2 tables, Tablette and Client. In Tablette there is a foreign key pointing to the Client table to identify the owner of the tablette.

Here's my controller code:

```
public function displayTablettesUser()
{
    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->getId();

    $var_tablette = Tablette::find()->where(['ID_fk_client' => 'user_id']);

    // Send toutes les tablettes du client
    return $this->render('profile', array('tablettes' => $var_tablette));
}
```

here's my php code to display the tablettes for the current user:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register ( $this );

foreach($tablettes as $tablette){
        echo($tablette->code)." : ".$tablette->iDFkClient->firstName."</br>";
}


?>
```

When i load my webpage, I get this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

I assume that I'm a beginner to this framework, I might have missed something but I don't know what.

Comment: try doing Tablette::find()->where(['ID_fk_client' => 'user_id'])->all();

Comment: I don't get the error anymore, but nothing is displayed ! (the user id is 1, i have tablet pointing with the client id 1) i don't really get why it doesn't work :( !

Comment: where(['ID_fk_client' => 'user_id']); - change this to where(['ID_fk_client' => $user_id]); and I guess you're good to go

Comment: i don't get anything too :/

Answer (score 0):

Besides the comments also, if you've generated models with Gii, you should have a function in Tablette model like:

```
public function getClient()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Client::className(), ['id' => 'ID_fk_client']);
}
```

So the view:

```
foreach($tablettes as $tablette){
        echo ($tablette->code)." : ".$tablette->getClient()->one()->firstName."</br>";
}
```